# Invoking "make -j2" failed, undefined reference during catkin_make

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi3, ros

Hi I am working on hector_slam with sick_tim, sensor tim571 on a raspberry pi 3 B+. i have this error when catkin_make. After checking i realise my /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/sick_tim/ file is empty. There is no libary files. How do i solve this?

Commands tat i run:

cd ~/catkin_ws/src

git clone https://github.com/uos/sick_tim.git

cd ~/catkin_ws/

catkin_make

This is the error that i get.
I am unable to solve this error, someone pls help me.

```
[ 38%] Linking CXX executable /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/sick_tim/sick_tim310_1130000m01
[ 41%] Linking CXX executable /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/sick_tim/sick_mrs1000
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_descriptor'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_get_config_descriptor'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_set_debug'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_close'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_init'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_detach_kernel_driver'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_open'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_release_interface'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_list'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_exit'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_unref_device'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_kernel_driver_active'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_ref_device'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_bulk_transfer'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_free_device_list'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_claim_interface'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_free_config_descriptor'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
sick_tim/CMakeFiles/sick_tim310_1130000m01.dir/build.make:141: recipe for target '/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/sick_tim/sick_tim310_1130000m01' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/sick_tim/sick_tim310_1130000m01] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1715: recipe for target 'sick_tim/CMakeFiles/sick_tim310_1130000m01.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [sick_tim/CMakeFiles/sick_tim310_1130000m01.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_descriptor'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_get_config_descriptor'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_set_debug'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_close'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_init'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_detach_kernel_driver'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_open'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_release_interface'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_list'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_exit'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_unref_device'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_kernel_driver_active'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_ref_device'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_bulk_transfer'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_free_device_list'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_claim_interface'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_free_config_descriptor'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
sick_tim/CMakeFiles/sick_mrs1000.dir/build.make:219: recipe for target '/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/sick_tim/sick_mrs1000' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/sick_tim/sick_mrs1000] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1518: recipe for target 'sick_tim/CMakeFiles/sick_mrs1000.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [sick_tim/CMakeFiles/sick_mrs1000.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j2" failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. Anyone that face similar problems may want to check out my [Solution](https://github.com/uos/sick_tim/issues/71#issuecomment-434196437) ^_^